# Yuko went out of the house and into the garden

Tags: conjunctions

I read the following in *English vocabulary in use* book.

> Yuko went out of the house **and into** the garden.

Is it common to use *and* with *into*?

Comment: The question is sort of funny (odd). /And/ can precede a preposition. What is a ** use book**??

Comment: "English vocabulary in use" is the name of the book, it is from Cambridge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that you had two sentences:

> Yuko went out of the house.
>   Yuko went into the garden.

These are both perfectly normal, correct sentences. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and), **and** can be used as a conjunction to join two parts of a sentence, one part happening after the other part. If we do that with the two sentences above, we get:

> Yuko went out of the house **and** Yuko went into the garden.

There are some duplicated words in that sentence. We can prune them out using a process called [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), giving this sentence:

> Yuko went out of the house **and** into the garden.

When you analyse the sentence in this way, you should be able to see that there is nothing special about the construction **and into**. It's just a consequence of taking two ordinary sentences, joining them with **and**, then removing the duplicated words.

Note that a preposition clause simply provides additional information to a sentence: you can add as many of these as you like to a sentence. **out of the house** and **into the garden** are both preposition phrases, so you could remove the **and**:

> Yuko went out of the house into the garden.

This would imply that the two things were part of the same **went** action, for example going through a doorway directly into the garden. The use of **and** would suggest two consecutive actions, for example going through a doorway and down a path leading to the garden.

Comment: Very nice answer.  I would just point out that removing the "and" could have unintended consequences.  The meaning is clear in this example, but "into the garden" could then describe the house, in which case Yuko just left the house headed to somewhere else.

Comment: @fixer1234: true, but this is only a footnote. I don't want to add a 'footnote  footnote' to cover "...the baby with the plastic teeth" situations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is both common and correct.

[Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+into%2C+and+in+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000)